# std::ofstream, Overwriting wrong file line

Tags: c++

I have a function which outputs data to a text file:

```
void File_IO::save( const std::string& path_ ) const
{

    const std::string file_name = path_ + this->local_time() + ".txt";
    std::ofstream outfile( file_name );

    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };


    outfile << '\n' << '\n' << "//--------------------------------- DATA:" << '\n' << '\n';

    long pos_beg = outfile.tellp();

    for( auto& i : vec )
    {
        outfile << i << '\n';
    }

    long pos_end = outfile.tellp();

    outfile << '\n' << "//---------------------------------------" << '\n' << '\n';



    //outfile.seekp( 0 );   
    //outfile << pos_beg << " " << pos_end << " " << pos_beg << " " << pos_end;
}
```

Output:

```
//--------------------------------- DATA:

One
Two
Three
Four

//---------------------------------------
```

The issue occurs at the end of the function when it comes to overwriting the first line with the start/end position of the data ...add these two lines:

```
outfile.seekp( 0 ); 
outfile << pos_beg << " " << pos_end << " " << pos_beg << " " << pos_end;
```

Output:

```
49 72 49 72---------------------------- DATA:

One
Two
Three
Four

//---------------------------------------
```

As you can see, there are two empty lines in the file before we get to the header but instead it overwrites these and partially deletes the header line which is the 3rd line in the file not the 1st as expected.

Another clue:

If I write only one var, it seems to work but still deletes one of the empty lines at the start of the file:

```
outfile.seekp( 0 ); 
outfile << pos_beg ;
```

Output:

```
49
//--------------------------------- DATA:

One
Two
Three
Four

//---------------------------------------
```

Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can edit my function to work as required?

ps
wont allow me to add relevant tags for some reason

Comment: Are you expecting the data in the file to automatically move to make room for the new stuff? How is this not behaving the way you want?

Comment: @Galik I'm expecting the new stuff to overwrite the existing data in the file & not move anything.  As described in the working example for: outfile.write() shown in the link below ...however write() is less convenient so hoping to do something similar with <<.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/seekp/

Comment: *"As you can see, there are two empty lines in the file"* Two empty lines are simply two `'\n'` characters, at offsets 0 and 1, followed by `'/'` character at offset 3. There is nothing magical about `'\n'` - it occupies one byte, and gets overwritten like any other. You seem to expect it to somehow reserve infinite space - that ain't how it works.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I didn't say it would "reserve infinite space" but if '\n' created an 'empty line' first time round, then why shouldn't I expect it to do the same again? ...so getting back to the question, how to create an empty line?

Answer (score 0):

Off the back of Igor's nudge in the right direction, adding the following line of code to the function seems to work:

```
outfile << "                                                     " << '\n';
```

Revised function:

```
void File_IO::save( const std::string& path_ ) const
{

    const std::string file_name = path_ + this->local_time() + ".txt";
    std::ofstream outfile( file_name );

    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

    // Edit
    outfile << "                                                     " << '\n';   
    // Edit

    outfile << '\n' << '\n' << "//--------------------------------- DATA:" << '\n' << '\n';

    long pos_beg = outfile.tellp();

    for( auto& i : vec )
    {
        outfile << i << '\n';
    }

    long pos_end = outfile.tellp();

    outfile << '\n' << "//---------------------------------------" << '\n' << '\n';



    outfile.seekp( 0 );   
    outfile << pos_beg << " " << pos_end << " " << pos_beg << " " << pos_end;
}
```

Output:

```
104 127 104 127                                      


//--------------------------------- DATA:

One
Two
Three
Four

//---------------------------------------
```

If someone can provide a better answer and say why, I'll accept that one over mine which seems a bit of a bodge.